# Binding Dictionary to MvxTableLayout monodroid MvvmCross

Tags: xamarin.android, mvvmcross

I have a dictionary with a dynamic number of rows in it that I would like to bind to a tablelayout in android with Mvvmcross. This doesn't need two way binding just a one way.

How is this accomplished? Is it best to not use a tableLayout? (this is how I would have done it without mvvmcross)

Is there a better way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It has been supported since vNext and a description can be seen in [GitHub Issue 110](https://github.com/slodge/MvvmCross/issues/110).

The binding language itself supports indices etc. which supports binding of dictionaries. I suspect you can bind the dictionary as you would a list to either a `ListView` or `TableLayout` depending on how and what you want to display.

Comment: +1 for everything here - only comments to add are: for a *dynamic* dictionary then you will perhaps want to inherit from dictionary to provide iNotifyCollectionChanged messages; and that overall it might be devtime easier and more runtime efficient to use an observablecollection rather than a dictionary - but it depends on your app requirements.